# Python with Selenium: Click intercepted and finding different span classes

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, automation

I'm trying to write a program that works like this:

1. Go to main page
2. Click the first item on the list (all items start with "item-"), which takes me into the next page.
3. Find a button with "A" on it and click it.
4. Find a "confirm" button and click it.
5. Go back, and to the same for item 2, item 3 etc.

I have two problems. Firstly the button with "A" on it, sometimes has more text than simply an "A" eg. "A" with "123" footnote. I don't know much about HTML, but this results in different span and div classes:

```
<div class="selectOne">
    <span class="selectObject-no-footnote">A</span>
</div>

<div class="selectOne-with-footnote">
    <span class="selectObject">A</span>
        <span class="selectFootnote">
            <span>123</span>
        </span>
</div>
```

They are never on the same page, but with my solution, the "A" button is not always pressed. It's difficult to say if it is because my solution is uncorrect or if it comes from the second problem. Often (it's random) when I go into the page with the buttons on it, some banner rolls down from the top of the page, and the whole site shifts in a way that my "Confirm" button is out of sight. The way I solved it is to just scroll down the site every time and only then start looking for buttons. Then it shouldn't matter if the banner rolls down or not, becuase in both cases button "A" and "Confirm" are visible. But still, I don't have 100% accuracy, and I sometimes get `click intercepted` exception. My code:

```
i=0
a=1
while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'item-')]")))
    items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'item-')]")
    try:
        items[i].click()

        try:
            try:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")
                WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='selectObject-no-footnote'][contains(text(),'A')]")))
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='selectObject-no-footnote'][contains(text(),'A')]").click()
            except Exception as e:
                a = 0
                print(e)


            if a==0:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")
                WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='selectObject'][contains(text(),'A')]")))
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='selectObject'][contains(text(),'A')]").click()
                a=1

            WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'confirm')))

            driver.find_element_by_id('confirm').click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        i += 1

        driver.back()

    except IndexError:
        print(items)
        print(i)

        break
```

Is there a different tool that could do this without having to worry about elements being covered by something or out of window? (Scrappy?)

Answer (score 0):

The overall logic is correct. I would suggest to make two changes, (This is in JAVA)

1) Find the button with text A using the following xpath. This should work for both case (A or A123)

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'selectObject')][contains(text(),'A')]");
button.click();
```

2) You can scroll down to the element and wait until the above element is visible & clickable on the page.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button);
```

Comment: In 1) you don't specify that you're looking for A, and there is more than one button with the same span class name, that's why I'm using contains('A'). Also, wouldn't your solution be much slower, since it has to iterate through all span classes and not just thorugh those specified by me, or is it unnoticeable? As for 2), how excatly do I scroll down to specific element?

Comment: Updated the xpath. It may be slower, but hardly noticeable. I also added the code for scrolling down to specific element on a page.

Comment: I beleve that now it clicks 100% of the buttons, but after a couple of first buttons it runs terribly slow (like 5 s to scroll down to the A button and click it). When I scroll down with window.scrollTo, it works well until something crashes. Also why Selenium can scroll right to the element, even when it's outside of the window, but can't click it?

Comment: @NotStudent you can click on the element, but it is not guaranteed if it is not in the view port. I am not sure why it takes 5s to scroll down. Is your script waiting on page doc to completely load?  If this answer served the purpose, do accept. thanks!